# Use custom Fields from a custom table in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-wordpress-pages

firstly thank you for your help. I am a complete noob at this. I come from a hardware side of IT but find programing interesting. I shall expose my issue as best I can. This will be a somewhat long post. I found on YouTube a video of what I am trying to accomplish and followed the link to the GitHub to download the code. Yes I did contact the original author but did not get an answer. From what I understand he was responding to a question on here but I cannot seem to find it and my issue is past what was talked about in the video. My use case is as follows: I need to be able to create a custom post of the listings type in my WordPress. The code was originally made for 5 fields. I have 30 fields for now and might end up needing more so I need this plug-in to be scalable. I also need it to support elementor/elementor pro. Now as I said this code is 99% from TechiePress all I did was add my fields and modify what needed to be modified to work with my table. I know this is not a sql issue as my table has only one row in it currently because I am testing. It is worth mentioning that some of my fields are empty and that is a real life case not every field is mandatory.

My current issues is that only the first 6 meta fields are being populated instead of all 30 and elementor is not supported. I get the following error for elementor

> Blockquote "Sorry, the content area was not found in your page.
> You must call 'the_content' function in the current template, in order for Elementor to work on this page."

Here is my code it is on pastebin because i was unable to copy and past it properly on here is kept making some code and some not.
[Plug-in Code](https://pastebin.com/fQ2yDx7D)

Here is my sql to create my table for reference

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_listingsdb`
(`c_number` char(20) NOT NULL
,`civic_number` text NULL
,`street` text NULL
,`mun` text NULL
,`postal` text NULL
,`number_of_rooms` text NULL
,`number_of_bathrooms` text NULL
,`number_of_powder_rooms` text NULL
,`room_one_type` text NULL
,`room_one_size` text NULL
,`room_one_comment` text NULL
,`room_two_type` text NULL
,`room_two_size` text NULL
,`room_two_comment` text NULL
,`room_three_type` text NULL
,`room_three_size` text NULL
,`room_three_comment` text NULL
,`room_four_type` text NULL
,`room_four_size` text NULL
,`room_four_comment` text NULL
,`room_five_type` text NULL
,`room_five_size` text NULL
,`room_five_comment` text NULL
,`room_six_type` text NULL
,`room_six_size` text NULL
,`room_six_comment` text NULL
,`room_seven_type` text NULL
,`room_seven_size` text NULL
,`room_seven_comment` text NULL
,`photo_one` text NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (`c_number`)
) ENGINE InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Here is a screen shoot of what happens on wordpress [wordpress metabox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXFAl.png)

I believe that is all the information I can think of that is worth mentioning. I did google this a lot but I did not find anything that might help so I turn to you the Heroes off the WEB. thank you once again

Comment: Being new to web development you run the risk of opening yourself up to security issues in the future so my suggestion is to abandon custom coding this and use [Advanced Custom Fields](https://advancedcustomfields.com/). ACF was specifically designed to solve issues like this. Also, it took me a while to learn that if I can't find solutions for a problem on the web I am probably making it more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @rolturn Thank you for your answer. I did try ACF but unfortunatly ACF has a random ID attributed to the post and i cannot find a way to customize that. I seem to have forgoten to say the my table will be updated automatically via csv every day. That is the reason i need my posts to be done automatically. If you know how to make ACF post id my c_number field by all means lets me know. Thank you for your time

Comment: ACF has a get_field(), [https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) function which you can use to get field by a custom name. Like you I initially was upset by the idea of the random key rendering the field useless. Also it has an update_field(), [https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) which you can use to populate with your CSV. For that, you would need to set up a function on your functions.php to import your data.